# JS: Combining equally indexed string array items into a new array. Example: ['a', 'b', 'c'] [1, 2, 3] = [a1, b2, c3]

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this example I am trying to add schools with their city. I have an array of schools and another array with their locations. They are both in the correct order. I just need to match index 0 from the first array with index 0 from array 2 to make a new array showing school and city. This is what I have so far:

```
const school = ['Brentwood', 'Gatewood', 'Stratford'];

const schoolCity = ['Sandersville', 'Eatonton', 'Macon']


const schoolPlusCity = school.map((skool) => {
  return skool + ', ' + schoolCity
});

console.log(schoolPlusCity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add index as the second parameter on [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback function and access the the city as `schoolCity[index]`

```js
const school = ['Brentwood', 'Gatewood', 'Stratford'];

const schoolCity = ['Sandersville', 'Eatonton', 'Macon']


const schoolPlusCity = school.map((skool, index) => {
  return skool + ', ' + schoolCity[index]
});

console.log(schoolPlusCity);
```

Comment: Much appreciated Eddie!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re okay with using a library, [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) provides [`zip`](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) which does just what you want:

```js
const school = ['Brentwood', 'Gatewood', 'Stratford']
const schoolCity = ['Sandersville', 'Eatonton', 'Macon']

const result = _.zip(school, schoolCity).map((pair) => pair.join(', '))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution, since you can do the same in python as well.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That is an interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do if you are looking for a solution with [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function for a change.

```js
const school = ['Brentwood', 'Gatewood', 'Stratford'];

const schoolCity = ['Sandersville', 'Eatonton', 'Macon']


const schoolPlusCity = school.reduce((arr, skool, index) => {
  arr.push(skool + ', ' + schoolCity[index]);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(schoolPlusCity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the hard codes solutions, you could use

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for takin an array of the wnated parts to join, which is easily to extend by adding some more parts and use
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting single parts in a new array for later taking
- [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the wanted style with comma separated values.

```js
const
    school = ['Brentwood', 'Gatewood', 'Stratford'],
    schoolCity = ['Sandersville', 'Eatonton', 'Macon'],
    schoolPlusCity = [school, schoolCity]
        .reduce(
            (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || []).concat(v)),
            []
        )
        .map(a => a.join(', '));         

console.log(schoolPlusCity);
```